# Converting numbers to words Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to write a piece of code that converts an input number into words. For example, if I input 420 it would output Four Two Zero. So far I have a dictionary and a way to convert the input into separate characters. However, I don't know how to combine the two and print an output. print(temp) does not work. Thank you. I cannot use num2words.

```
def convert( number ):
    str(word)=number
    [int(word)for word in str(number)]
    dict = {
    "0": "Zero ",
    "1": "One ",
    "2": "Two ",
    "3": "Three ",
    "4": "Four ",
    "5": "Five ",
    "6": "Six ",
    "7": "Seven ",
    "8": "Eight ",
    "9": "Nine "
    }
    print(word)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you need function here. You can simply try as following:

```
mydict = {"0": "Zero ",
          "1": "One ",
          "2": "Two ",
          "3": "Three ",
          "4": "Four ",
          "5": "Five ",
          "6": "Six ",
          "7": "Seven ",
          "8": "Eight ",
          "9": "Nine "
          }
num = 420
# for each letter in string value of number
for ch in str(num):
    # get the letter from dictionary and print the word
    print(mydict[ch], end=' ')
```

Or using one line with `list comprehension`:

```
print(*[mydict[ch] for ch in str(num)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your function like this:

```
def convert( number ):
    word = ""
    dict = {
    "0": "Zero ",
    "1": "One ",
    "2": "Two ",
    "3": "Three ",
    "4": "Four ",
    "5": "Five ",
    "6": "Six ",
    "7": "Seven ",
    "8": "Eight ",
    "9": "Nine "
    }
    for i in str(number):
        word += dict[i]
    return word
convert(532)
# 'Five Three Two '
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to:

```
def Prob0( num ):
    for temp in str(num):
        dict = {
        "0": "Zero ",
        "1": "One ",
        "2": "Two ",
        "3": "Three ",
        "4": "Four ",
        "5": "Five ",
        "6": "Six ",
        "7": "Seven ",
        "8": "Eight ",
        "9": "Nine "
        }
        print(dict[temp])

Prob0(420)
```